# How to keep constant UI in portrait and Land scape mode in android

Tags: android, user-interface, uibutton, word-wrap

In portrait mode it looking like:

[image]

But in Land scape mode showing like:

[image]

Here I need to get UI same in Land scape mode as like portrait mode. 
How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your need is don't rotate UI on screen rotation, am i right?

Comment: No, When I rotates it should show as like portrait mode but here the 'From time' and 'To time' buttons are expanding as shown.

Comment: So, i think lot of changes needed for your xml design. Or you need to do separate design xml under the folder layout-land

Answer (score 1):

Mention the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for that activity in manifest file of this application

Comment: It only supports portrait mode only but I need two modes but same UI

Comment: if you want same ui in landscape you nee dto maintain layout-land folder ,Please go through this link  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html,and  remove that android:screenOrientation="portrait" property for that activity in manifest file

Comment: @ Praveena Getting 404 Error file not found. :( Can you please explain what we can do or send me any other related link for this.

Comment: follow this link,it might be helpful http://android.programmerguru.com/android-landscape-layout-example/

Comment: In the above link he given for Linear layout.But here I am using Relative layout. How can I change it? If i changed it to relative there are lot of errors in xml file.